# Cordova Status bar plugin doesn't work in android when keyboard pops up

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, statusbar, hybrid-mobile-app

I have used the cordova plugin - "cordova-plugin-statusbar", to hide the status bar on my hybrid app. But when the keyboard pops out, the status bar becomes visible again forever. 
Please note - this works perfect in iOS, the issue is in android only

Comment: Please show your config.xml file.

Comment: PFB the part which matters :
           <feature name="StatusBar">
           <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar"       onload="false"/>
           </feature>

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, `2.1.3` fails `2.0.0` works. I have logged a bug [CB-11197](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11197).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the version of the plugin created the issue, I downgraded the plugin to version 2.0, which is working perfect.

Comment: This worked for me.  I uninstalled the previous plugin.  I then downloaded the 2.0.0 version of the plugin.  I extracted it into the download folder on my MAC.  I Then I did a `cordova plugin add ~/Downloads/cordova-plugin-statusbar-2.0.0/`  Then a `cordova prepare` and all is good now.